# How to Set Overhang tag in all Resolution?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I set overhang tag in my XML file like below.

```
<Overhang
      translation="[100,10]"   
      logoUri="pkg:/images/logo.png" 
      optionsText="Menu"
      optionsAvailable="true"
      height="170"
      />
```

I use Roku Device both the resolution 720P and 1080P, But I can only set one resolution proper not both resolution. Is there any way to both the resolution display proper.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ui_resolutions=fhd` in your manifest, and then give Your overhang width, height and translation the values only for fhd resolution. `ui_resolutions=fhd` will tell the Roku  that You will take care of fhd resolution and that ROKU should take care and scale from this resolution to hd and sd.
You can find more about this in the [link](https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/core-concepts/specifying-display-resolution.md). 
Take a good look at `autoscaling guidelines` section.

If You don't want to do it like that and still would like to handle `fhd` and `hd`, please check [ifDeviceInfo](https://developer.roku.com/en-ca/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifdeviceinfo.md) and functions like `GetUIResolution()`, `GetDisplaySize()`.